# Sql Server - Query help (group by with having MAX)

Tags: sql, sql-server, group-by, exists, having

HI,

I'm having a huge problem with one query, this is the data that I have in my table:

```
entityId             groupId              groupDepth
-------------------- -------------------- -----------
NULL                 1090                 0
56                   1090                 1
222                  1090                 1
226                  1090                 1
227                  1090                 1
228                  1090                 1
234                  1090                 1
248                  1090                 2
249                  1090                 2
250                  1090                 2
251                  1090                 2
252                  1090                 1
256                  1090                 1
261                  1090                 1
288                  1090                 1
294                  1090                 1
300                  1090                 1
4691                 1090                 1
4694                 1090                 1
4697                 1090                 1
```

So what I would like to do, is to obtain the row with the highest groupDepth when given the entityId and groupId. Example results:

```
input: entityId = 294, groupId = 1090
entityId             groupId              groupDepth
-------------------- -------------------- -----------
294                  1090                 1


input: entityId = 113, groupId = 1090
entityId             groupId              groupDepth
-------------------- -------------------- -----------
NULL                 1090                 0
```

I was thinking about something like this:

```
SELECT * FROM [dbo].[EntityGroup] a 
WHERE EXISTS
(
    SELECT   groupId
    FROM     [dbo].[EntityGroup] b
    WHERE    
              (b.entityId is null or b.entityId = 294) AND
              b.groupId = a.groupId
    GROUP BY  b.groupId
    HAVING    a.groupDepth = max(b.groupDepth) and
              a.entityId = b.entityId 
)
```

Any help will be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
SELECT entityID, groupId, groupDepth
FROM EntityGroup  t
WHERE groupDepth = (SELECT MAX(groupDepth) FROM EntityGroup  e WHERE COALESCE(e.entityID,-1) = COALESCE(t.entityId,-1) AND e.groupId = t.groupID)
GROUP BY entityID, groupId, groupDepth
```

Should work if I understood you correctly

**EDIT**

```
SELECT entityID, groupId, groupDepth
FROM EntityGroup    t
WHERE groupDepth = (SELECT MAX(groupDepth) FROM @Temp  e WHERE e.entityID = t.entityId AND e.groupId = t.groupID)
GROUP BY entityID, groupId, groupDepth
UNION
SELECT entityID, groupId, groupDepth
FROM EntityGroup    t
WHERE groupDepth = (SELECT MAX(groupDepth) FROM @Temp e WHERE e.groupId = t.groupID AND e.entityId IS NULL) AND t.entityId IS NULL
GROUP BY entityID,groupId, groupDepth
```

Comment: If I specify the entityId that doesn't exist in the EntityGroup table, I will not receive the NULL row - please refer to my second example

Answer (score 0):

How about this?

```
DECLARE @entityId INT = 294
DECLARE @groupId INT = 1090

SELECT TOP 1 entityId, groupid, Max(groupDepth) AS groupDepth
FROM EntityGroup
WHERE (entityId is null OR entityId = @entityId)
AND groupId = @groupId
GROUP BY entityId, groupId
order by entityId desc
```

**EDIT**: Updated SQL to order by entityId descending and take the first one will give the correct answer for the specified cases

Comment: This would be good, by I get two rows in my result set - one with the NULL value as entityId and one with the 294 when I should get only one row.

Comment: @MonkeyCoder - Right. I've edited the answer to get only 1 row now